# Creating a index page to go to on launch for ASP.Net Core Web API Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui

Essentially when I created the project and created a functional API where the user can create, delete, etc information from a database and run it I get the swagger UI that I can use to test that API.

Now that I know it works I want to start actually building pages on the website rather than go to swagger. However, even when I tried setting a default page in a web.config file to my Index.cshtml it went to swagger instead.

Basically my question is, how do I change this?

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to remove the swagger launch setting. Got to the Properties folder and open the `launchSettings.json` file, remove or clear the `launchUrl` property.

[image]

Then, you can create a `wwwroot` folder and add the default page: in the default page, you can add a hyperlink to navigate to the swagger UI.

[image]

After that, add the following code to the Configure method (if you are using Asp.net 6, you can add them in the Program.cs file):

```
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        var options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
        options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
        options.DefaultFileNames.Add("mydefault.html");
        app.UseDefaultFiles(options);

        app.UseStaticFiles();


        app.UseRouting();
```

Finally, running the API application, the result as below:

[image]

Besides, if you are using the MVC view, you could refer to the following steps:

[Note] By using this method, still need to remove the launch setting relates the swagger.

1. Add a HomeController with Index Action.
2. Add an Index View page
3. Register the controller and view service in the ConfigureServices:

   ```
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
   ```
4. Configure the endpoint

   ```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",
       pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    });
   ```

Then, when running the API application, it will show the Home Controller Index View page.

Comment: .Net 6 project template already cares to conditionally launch swagger depending on app.Environment.IsDevelopment() so no need to edit launchsettings.json if you just want to avoid swagger on production

Answer (score 3):

First, create a directory in the project root with the name `wwwroot` - it can be any name and add your HTML files inside that - you need an `index.html` file. If you're using .NET 5 modify your startup.cs and if you're using .NET 6, modify your program.cs and add the following code.

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() 
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot"))
});
```

Now you run the app, you will be able to see the index.html in the browser. Note: Sometimes browsers cache the swagger UI even if you change the file - to fix this open your browser developer tools and right-click on the reload/refresh button - you will get 3 options, choose the `Empty Cache and Hard Reload` option. It will solve your problem.